# Getting response from jQuery form POST

Tags: jquery, post, response

I'm using jQuery to POST a form without leaving the page it's on. The PHP page the form is being POSTed to sends an email and echos a '1' for success or a '0' for failure.

I would like to retrieve the contents of that PHP page ('1' or '0') and display it in an alert box on the page with the form (the page we stay on, even after POSTing).

I have tried this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var $form = $('#confirmationForm');
  $form.submit(function(){                
    $.post($(this).attr('action'), $(this).serialize(), function(response){
      alert(response);
    },'json');
    return false;
  });
});
```

The form is POSTed just fine, and the PHP script functions as normal (the email is sent), but no response is displayed.

Comment: Have you echoed your value in the action page? If it is echoed, that will be your response

Comment: Yes an answer is echoed no matter what the result is on the action page.

Comment: Try looking at the response in fiddler or chrome developer tools

Comment: What is the response you are getting?

Comment: The alert box simply doesn't show up. Not even empty

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to echo the response from the php script and you are done

For example

```
 if(mysql_query($query))
        $response_array['status'] = 'success';  
    else 
        $response_array['status'] = 'error';
header('Content-type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($response_array);

?>
```

On the client side

```
success: function(data) {
      if(data.status == 'success')
          alert("Thank you you succeeded");
      else if(data.status == 'error')
          alert("Oops there was an error!");
    },
```

Hope you got my point.

Cheers!!!